# ListBox1.List generates Object defined error

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I am trying to export my userform listbox contents to a new workbook.

I am getting the error as I commented in the code.

```
Private Sub ExportListBoxContents_Click()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlsh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlApp.Workbooks.Add

Set xlsh = xlApp.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1)

For j = 1 To ListBox1.ListCount

    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ColumnCount
        xlsh.Cells(j, i).Value = ListBox1.List(j - 1, i) '<----Object defined error
    Next i

Next j

xlApp.Visible = True

Set xlsh = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I have managed to solve it after so many hours and searching.

All I had to do is amend the line from this:

```
xlsh.Cells(j, i).Value = ListBox1.List(j - 1, i)
```

To this:

```
xlsh.Cells(j , i).Value = ListBox1.Column(j - 1, i - 1)
```